# What are the differences between two climax of Solo?

Tags: plot-explanation, alternate-version, solo

I'm talking about the Malayalam/Tamil movie [Solo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6613814/)

After finishing it [IMDb Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6613814/trivia?ref_=tt_ql_2) shows that there is two climax scene. The 4th story has two different ending, one is shown in Tamil region and another is shown in Kerala region. One is director's cut and another one is forcefully edited by the producer. The director "Bejoy Nambiar" tweeted about it:

> For all those asking about the changed ending. It has been done without my knowledge and consent.Good or Bad I stand by the film I made...

The version that I watched has a ending like

> Rudra went to the marriage ceremony and said sorry to both bride and groom.

What's the other climax? Can anyone please tell me? I Googled but can't find any document that shows the changes between the two version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They didn't change the whole climax scene.

In one version Rudra's father saying him that the girl he loved is actually his step sister, so he can not marry her.

On the other hand, the scene is same but there is no dialogue as it is muted and audience needs to understand from their reaction and background score.

This change was made because the film got poor audience response due to the dialogue delivery of the conversation.